# Can't access Sql Server after installing Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, active-directory, sql-server-2008

I had SQL Server 2008 set up with databases and sites running, then installed MS Exchange on the server which required Active Directory before moving forward.

After installing both, my sites were no longer connected to the databases and I couldn't connect to SQL Server at all through the management console both remotely and directly on the server.

Does anyone know what parameters may have needed changing to be able to log on to SQL Server?
Or if there's some other step I missed after installing these things that I need to do in order to fix SQL Server?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by making sure the SQL Server services are running.  They may have been stopped during installation.

Administrative Tools > Services